# Generación de jquery desde AngularJS(Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Tengo un inconveniente al generar dinámicamente `div` desde angular para `html`. El inconveniente está en que por cada `div` debo generar un script, `jquery`, que lo controle dinámicamente. Con el html no hay problema, genera muy bien, pero el evento `clic` del `jquery` no lo reconoce.

Para imprimir dinámicamentedesde el js angular, hago lo siguiente:

```
Lsttotales = document.getElementById("pnlTotales");
Lstscripts = document.getElementById("pnlscripts");
var a = "";
var b = "";
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.lstResultado.length; i++) {
    a += "<script>$(\"pnlresultado"+i+"\").click(function(){})";
    b += "<div>..."
}
Lstscripts.innerHTML = a;
LstTotales.innerHTML = b;
$compile(document.getElementById('pnlTotales'))($scope);
```

Cabe mencionar que el script y las listas se presentan correctamente en la vista pero no responde a lo generado que sea scripts, a pesar de que este sí está insertado en el html.

**EDIT**

tengo generando desde el javascript, angular los diferentes paneles dinámicos según la lista se van agrupando, pero necesito que en cada panel tenga su función contraer y expandir. Lo que no he logrado.

```
                 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lstFactura.length; i++) {
                    //Realizar la logica para separar la lista de planillas
                    if (primero == 0) {
                        ruc_IA = $scope.lstFactura[i].ruc_Proveedor_IA;
                        desc_Moneda = $scope.lstFactura[i].desc_Moneda;
                        primero = 1;
                    }


                    if ($scope.lstFactura[i].ruc_Proveedor_IA == ruc_IA && i + 1 < $scope.lstFactura.length && $scope.lstFactura[i].desc_Moneda == desc_Moneda) {

                        $scope.agrupacion[lista].factura.push($scope.lstFactura[i]);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (i + 1 == $scope.lstFactura.length) {
                            $scope.agrupacion[lista].factura.push($scope.lstFactura[i]);
                        }
                        a += "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                                            "jQuery.document(\"#headerPnlResultado" + i + "\").click(function () {" +
                                                "alert('chemito');" +
                                                "if (jQuery.document(\"#contentPnlResultado" + i + ":first\").is(\":hidden\")) {" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#icoPnlResultado" + i + "\").removeClass(\"fa fa-plus-square fa-lg\");" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#icoPnlResultado" + i + "\").addClass(\"fa fa-minus-square fa-lg\");" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#contentPnlResultado" + i + "\").slideDown(\"slow\");" +
                                                "} else {" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#icoPnlResultado" + i + "\").removeClass(\"fa fa-minus-square fa-lg\");" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#icoPnlResultado" + i + "\").addClass(\"fa fa-plus-square fa-lg\");" +
                                                    "jQuery.document(\"#contentPnlResultado" + i + "\").slideUp();" +
                                                "}" +
                                            "});" +
                                            "</script>";
                        b += "<div id='pnlContenidoDinamico" + i + "' class='panel panel-default' ng-init='variable = \"users" + i + "\"'>" +
                            "<div id='headerPnlResultado" + i + "' class='panel-heading panel-heading-edit'     ng-click='variable = \"dol" + i + "\"'>" +
                                                "<table width='100%'>" +
                                                    "<tr>" +
                                                       "<td width='3%'>" +
                                                            "<div class='content-arrow_box'>" +
                                                                "<div class='arrow_box'>" +
                                                                    "<span class='fa fa-folder-open-o fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
                                                               " </div>" +
                                                           " </div>" +
                                                        "</td>" +
                                                        "<td class='title-tab'>" +
                                                           " <span ng-show='agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].prioridad!=\"\"  && agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].prioridad!=null'>  <span class='fa  fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></span> Prioridad: {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].prioridad}} <br /></span>" +


                                                           " <span class='fa  fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
                                                          "  BT: {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].cuenta}} - {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].nom_Girador}} | RUC: {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].ruc}} | Moneda: {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].desc_Moneda}} | {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].desc_Presuncion}} | {{agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura[0].desc_Linea}}" +

                                                        "</td>" +
                                                        "<td class='ico-title-tab'>" +
                                                            "<i id='icoPnlResultado" + i + "' class='fa fa-minus-square fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                        "</td>" +
                                                     "</tr>" +
                                                "</table>" +
                                            "</div>" +
                                            "<div class='panel-body'>" +
                                                "<div id='contentPnlResultado" + i + "' class='content-tab' ng-class='\"hidden\": variable === \"dol" + i + "\"'>" +
                                                    "<div class='row'>" +
                                                        "<div class='table-responsive col-md-12'>" +
                                                            "<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                            "<i class='icomoon icon-file-excel' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                            "<strong> Información Adicional </strong>" +
                                                            "&nbsp;" +
                                                            "<i class='fa fa-angle-double-right' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                            "<i class='fa fa-angle-double-right' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                            "<i class='fa fa-angle-double-right' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                            "&nbsp;" +
                                                            "<strong> Factura(s): </strong> {{FacturasValidas}} <strong> Importe Total: </strong> {{simbolo_moneda}}  {{importe_total|number:2}}" +

                                                            "<span ng-show='Procesados == \"1\"'>" +
                                                                "&nbsp;" +
                                                                "<i class='fa fa-angle-double-right' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                                "<i class='fa fa-angle-double-right' style='color: #009933;' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
                                                                "<strong> Factura(s) Procesadas: </strong> {{FacturasValidasOK}}  &nbsp; <strong> Importe Total Procesado: </strong> {{simbolo_moneda}}  {{importe_total|number:2}}" +
                                                            "</span>" +
                                                         "</div>" +
                                                        "<br />" +
                                                        "<div class='table-responsive col-md-12'>" +
                                                            "<table class='table table-hover'>" +
                                                                "<thead>" +
                                                                    "<tr>" +
                                                                        "<th>N°</th>" +
                                                                        "<th>Adquirente</th>" +
                                                                        "<th>Razón Social</th>" +
                                                                        "<th>N° Doc.</th>" +
                                                                        "<th>Monto</th>" +
                                                                        "<th>Detalle</th>" +
                                                                    "</tr>" +
                                                                "</thead>" +
                                                                "<tbody>" +
                                                                    "<tr class='ng-scope' ng-repeat='oFactura in agrupacion[" + lista + "].factura'>" +
                                                                        "<td>{{$index+1}}</td>" +
                                                                        "<td>{{oFactura.ruC_Adquirente}}</td>" +
                                                                        "<td>{{oFactura.nom_Adquirente}}</td>" +
                                                                        "<td>{{oFactura.factura}}</td>" +
                                                                        "<td><p align=right> {{oFactura.simbolo_MDA}} {{oFactura.importe_Neto_Pago_IA|number:2}} </p></td>" +
                                                                        "<td>" +
                                                                            "<button ng-click='btnSeleccionar(oFactura)' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mdlFactura'" +
                                                                                    "class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' ng-show='oFactura.status=\"0\"'" +
                                                                                    "title='Ver Datos de la Factura'>" +
                                                                                "<span class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
                                                                            "</button>" +
                                                                            "<button ng-click='btnSeleccionar(oFactura)' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mdlError'" +
                                                                                    "class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' ng-show='oFactura.status==\"1\"'" +
                                                                                    "title='Ver Datos de la Factura'>" +
                                                                                "<span class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
                                                                            "</button>" +
                                                                            "<button ng-click='btnSeleccionar(oFactura)' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mdlExcel'" +
                                                                                    "class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' ng-show='oFactura.status==\"2\"'" +
                                                                                    "title='Ver Datos de la Factura'>" +
                                                                                "<span class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
                                                                            "</button>" +
                                                                        "</td>" +
                                                                    "</tr>" +
                                                                "</tbody>" +
                                                            "</table>" +
                                                        "</div>" +
                                                    "</div>" +
                                                "</div>" +
                                            "</div></div>";



                        if (i + 1 != $scope.lstFactura.length) {
                            lista++;
                            $scope.agrupacion.push({ factura: [] });
                            ruc_IA = $scope.lstFactura[i].ruc_Proveedor_IA;
                            desc_Moneda = $scope.lstFactura[i].desc_Moneda;                                
                            $scope.agrupacion[lista].factura.push($scope.lstFactura[i]);
                        }
                        lstScripts.innerHTML = a;
                        //$compile(document.getElementById('scripts'))($scope);
                        lstTotales.innerHTML = b;
                        $compile(document.getElementById('pnlTotales'))($scope);
                    }
                }


                //Redireccionamos a la otra página
                //$location.path("/CargaFacturas/Registro");
            }
        }).error(function (error) {
            $('#myModal').modal("hide");
            alert("Muestra panel en vez de esto");

        }).finally(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal("hide");
        });
    };
```

Este código Jquery dinámico, es decir se va a generar según la lista que se forme. se peuden tener n div con esa propiedad click.

```
    $('#headerPnlCarga').click(function () {

        if ($("#contentPnlCarga:first").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#icoPnlCarga").removeClass("fa fa-plus-square fa-lg");
            $("#icoPnlCarga").addClass("fa fa-minus-square fa-lg");
            $("#contentPnlCarga").slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $("#icoPnlCarga").removeClass("fa fa-minus-square fa-lg");
            $("#icoPnlCarga").addClass("fa fa-plus-square fa-lg");
            $("#contentPnlCarga").slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Te sugiero coloques el codigo más complet y el error (si lo hay) que se muestre (aún cuando sea en la **consola** para mejor percepción de tu situación; por ejemplo en el código que pusiste el **a+="<script>$("pnlresultado").click...";** debe ser **a+="<script>$(\"pnlresultado\").click...";** o que cambies a comillas simple lo externo de la cadena y doble comillas lo interno o viceversa; así mismo en **a+="<script>$("pnlresultado").click...";** ¿*$("pnlresultado")* es un tag?; por que de ser id sería *$("#pnlresultado")* y si fuera una clase *$(".pnlresultado")*; asi por el estilo...

Comment: Hola roberto gracias por tu respuesta. En si no me da ningún error el programa, lo que pasa es que no se ejecuta el jquery que armado en la variable a, la función del click, al html que genera si lo copio y pego en un html este si funciona correctamente por lo que dedusco que sea un problema al generar html desde el javascript

Comment: Pasa usar Angular o angularjs correctamente lo mejor que se puede hacer es ignorar la existencia de jQuery. Y lo crear un tag <script> para añadir más código en lugar de tenerlo ya en tu código es muy rebuscado e innecesario. Creo que deberías replantearte la forma de implementar lo que sea que estás haciendo

Comment: Hola pablo, el problema es que lo hago asi porque intento generar unos paneles, div dinámicos cada uno con un evento independiente. Mi problema está en que mi cliente viene con n facturas de mercado con diferentes items este carga los excel donde yo los agrupo por producto y moneda. Al poderse tener n tipos de productos opté por generar la lista ordenarlo y generar el html desde el javascript

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando angular evita el uso de JQuery. Es una practica algo "guarra".

Para los eventos click en angular basta con colocar [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-click-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario como lo dices  quiero cambiar el cambio de estilos que hacia por el ng-click edito la pregunta

Comment: @Zerart Creo que no entiendo bien la pregunta. ¿Que quieres conseguir? Un div que se despliegue y muestre mas información... tipico menu desplegable... el código que has puesto no se ejecuta y no consigo ver lo que buscas.

Comment: Asi es asi como está el jquery de la pregunta principal, el inconveniente es que este script es para cada panel. Y en este caso pueso generar n panels, ya que la cantidad depende de u a lista que carga el usuario desde un excel